# Entrada e saída padrão (utilizando programas em C)

Tags: c

Eu tenho um programa que imprime algo, e outro que lê alguma coisa e imprime outra, gostaria de saber se tem como conectar a saída de um com a entrada de outro.

A gambiarra que eu fiz foi, passar a saída de um para `txt`, e depois pedi para o outro ler esse `txt`, da seguinte forma:

```
 ./teste > texto.txt; ./1024 < texto.txt
```

[image: Entrada e saída padrão]

Tem como fazer isso de maneira direta?
Como por exemplo:

```
./teste > ./1024 (dessa maneira não funciona)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use o operador pipe(|). Ele faz justamente o que você precisa: pega o output de um programa e usa como input de outro:

```
./teste | ./1024
```